# JPA/JPQL Ad Hoc Join

Tags: jpa, hql, jpql

My question is similar to other related questions except I am using Spring Data and want to return a custom object. Though the custom object i want to return has no reference to many items, the many items do have a reference to my custom object.

database:

```
CREATE TABLE tree (id integer, type text, leave_color text, category integer);
CREATE TABLE tree_category (id integer, name text);

INSERT INTO tree_category VALUES (1, "Tall");
INSERT INTO tree_category VALUES (2, "Short");


INSERT INTO tree VALUES (1, "Evergreen", "green", 1);
INSERT INTO tree VALUES (2, "Oak"  , "green", 1);
INSERT INTO tree VALUES (3, "Purple Tree"  , "purple", 2);
INSERT INTO tree VALUES (3, "Short Green Tree"  , "green", 2);
```

Java:

```
class TreeCategory {
    int id;
    String name;
    //EAGER fetching set
    List<Tree> trees;
}

class Tree {
    int id;
    String type;
    String leaveColor;
    int categoryId;
}
```

Spring Data Query:

```
@Query(value="select tc from TreeCategory tc "
     + "join Tree t on t.categoryId = tc.id "
     + "where t.leaveColor = 'green'"
Collection<TreeCategory> getGreenLeavesByCategory();
```

It keeps returning TreeCategoryS filled with everything.
i want the "Tall" category with Evergreen and Oak but
"Short" category to only have "Short Green Tree".

how do i accomplish this?

Comment: I'm surprised that your code even _runs_, as it isn't valid JPQL.  Please include the real entity definitions.

Comment: sorry, i work on an intranet site and the company doesn't like us downloading code. not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the answer a couple days ago but someone else may run into this so i'll post. join fetch solved the problem. not sure why i have to do the distinct. i should do show-sql just to see what the query is that is generated.

```
@Query(value="select distinct tc from TreeCategory tc "
     + "join fetch Tree t "
     + "where t.leaveColor = 'green'"
Collection<TreeCategory> getGreenLeavesByCategory();
```